# Using php7.0 with apache server on debian

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, debian

I'm running raspbian and am trying to use php7.0 with my apache web server. I have tried everything to install it to no avail, the PHP code simply doesn't run. I have php7.0 installed with

> sudo apt-get install apache2 php7.0 php7.0-curl php7.0-gd php7.0-imap
>   php7.0-json php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-mysql php7.0-opcache php7.0-xmlrpc
>   libapache2-mod-php7.0

I have configured apache to open index.php and it does, however, the code is simply displayed in the browser and doesn't run. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Did you enable the php module in Apache? Did you register PHP extension to php module?

Comment: I'm not sure I have tried before a while ago, would you be able to explain how to do that please?

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php7/php7_apache_configuration.htm

Comment: isn't that for windows?

Comment: nope... I'm not using Apache anymore (using nginx) but i can have a look at a server for the correct things you need. Give me a few seconds

Comment: 1st: do  apachectl -t to check if the config files are ok. 2nd Check at /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ that you have a php7.load and a php7.conf . If so, view the php7.load file to check if has the correct path to the php7 module.

Comment: ah thank you, I checked the mods-enabled folder and I dont have those php files, how would I aquire them?

Comment: libapache2-mod-php7.0 should have created those files. try to re-install  libapache2-mod-php7.0

Comment: ah! works great now, thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to re-install libapache2-mod-php7.0  so that apache modules configuration would be created.